# How to format Date & Time stamps while inside create table function?

Tags: datetime, ms-access, properties, formatting, vba

In my (newbie) DAO db, my table is successfully being created, however, no data is being entered into the date and timestamps. My goal is to have the local user's current datestamp and timestamp enter automatically into the Datestamp and Timestamp fields with formatting after they are created. Can anyone help me figure out where I am going wrong, and fix this? Thank you!

```
Function UALCreate()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Dim fld As Field
   Dim p As Property
   Dim pr As Property

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("UserActivityLog")

   With tdf
      Set fld = .CreateField("UserActivityLog_ID", dbGUID)
      fld.Attributes = dbFixedField
      fld.DefaultValue = "genGUID()"
      .Fields.Append fld

      Set fld = .CreateField("Owner_ID", dbLong)
      .Fields.Append fld

      .Fields.Append .CreateField("Activity", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("CurrentForm", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("LastForm", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("Datestamp", dbDate)

      .Fields.Append .CreateField("Timestamp", dbDate)

      .Fields.Append .CreateField("UserName", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("User_ID", dbLong)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("UserTypeID", dbLong)
   End With

   db.TableDefs.Append tdf

   Set fld = tdf.Fields("Datestamp")
   Set p = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "mm/dd/yyyy")
   Set fld = tdf.Fields("Timestamp")
   Set pr = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "hh:mm:ss")
   fld.Properties.Append p
   fld.Properties.Append pr
   Set p = Nothing
   Set pr = Nothing

   Set fld = Nothing
   Set tdf = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing
   Debug.Print "UserActivityLog"
End Function
```

Comment: And as an aside, if I used the wrong terminology, I apologize in advance, I did try to be correct. :)

Comment: FWIW, you'd have to move `fld.Properties.Append p` directly after setting `p` to make your code work (because `fld` was already set to the other field). But as Gustav wrote, use a single field and apply formatting on display.

Answer (score 0):

> .. with formatting after they are created

Forget about that. Instead, always apply a format when you *display* or print the data.

And you don't need two fields to hold the date and time. It is much easier to combine them and set the value with `Now`.

Comment: Gustav & @Andre, I'd appreciate a pointer on etiquette; both of you helped in answering my question, so by whom do I mark it correctly as answered? This particular table is a temp table feeding a permanent table; however, I cannot display the same field in two places (documents) in two different manners, hence the need for separate fields with separate formats. As it is DAO, research shows I cannot use Now(), hence the question. Corrected code to follow in the next comment for whomever may follow me having the same question. I also inserted the first record in the code. Thanks again, folks!

Comment: @Andre & Gustav, I spoke to soon. Upon checking several iterations, the code works for the first record with the dummy information, but then  further records do not insert the user's local information. In other words, it isn't picking up the date and time stamps. I removed the code for the p and pr variables as I finally got what you were saying about displaying it; I can show the date field twice and have the permanent table display the fields as needed. But that still leaves the data entry portion empty. As my code below did not work, I'm removing it to keep down confusion. Any suggestions?

Comment: As a thought, if I put Now() as the display default into the permanent table, it will show all the fields with the current time and date of conversion to the permanent table, will it not, rather than the time and date the user actually created the record?

Comment: Uh, I don't follow. Your code creates a table, that's all. No data is entered. And why shouldn't you be able to display the same field in two places with different formats?

Comment: I've undeleted the code which includes the first record being added. The code which adds subsequent records is contained inside a Public SQL statement which works perfectly but does not insert the Date and Time stamps; these must be inserted by the system automatically at the time of the record creation using the default `Now()` in the table. Does that help? And I have no idea how to display the same field in two places on the same form with two different formats. My brain just can't wrap around that one. But that's a separate issue that can be tackled later. This is more important. :)

Comment: 1. Access cannot add a timestamp automatically "by the system", but you can easily adjust your code or SQL to do so. 2. Create a textbox and bind it to the same field. A true no-brainer(!).

Comment: When I create the table as a permanent table and run the record-creating SQL statement, setting the Date and Timestamp fields with the `Now()` default, it works perfectly as I have said. What I need to do is create the table as a temporary table so it can be deleted after use. I don't understand how creating a textbox on a form would help if the underlying bound table field has not changed, but thanks anyway. I'll try to resolve my issue another way. I appreciate yours and @Andre 's efforts.

Comment: 1. There is no such thing as a temporary table in Access. You can create, use, and (manually) delete a table in the same or, preferably, in a separate database. 2. You didn't mention a changed or not changed table field but: "I have no idea how to display the same field in two places on the same form with two different formats." This is what "creating a textbox on a form" will solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
Function UALCreate()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Dim fld As Field
   Dim p As Property
   Dim pr As Property
   Dim rs As Recordset

   Set db = CurrentDb()
   Set tdf = db.CreateTableDef("UserActivityLog")

   With tdf
      Set fld = .CreateField("UserActivityLog_ID", dbGUID)
      fld.Attributes = dbFixedField
      fld.DefaultValue = "genGUID()"
      .Fields.Append fld

      Set fld = .CreateField("Owner_ID", dbLong)
      .Fields.Append fld

      .Fields.Append .CreateField("Activity", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("CurrentForm", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("LastForm", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("Datestamp", dbDate)

      .Fields.Append .CreateField("Timestamp", dbDate)

      .Fields.Append .CreateField("UserName", dbText, 50)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("User_ID", dbLong)
      .Fields.Append .CreateField("UserTypeID", dbLong)
   End With

   db.TableDefs.Append tdf
   CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh

   Set fld = Nothing
   Set p = fld
   Set fld = tdf.Fields("Datestamp")
   Set p = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "mm/dd/yyyy")
   fld.Properties.Append p
   Set p = Nothing

   Set fld = Nothing
   Set p = fld
   Set fld = tdf.Fields("Timestamp")
   Set p = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "hh:mm:ss")
   fld.Properties.Append p
   Set p = Nothing

   Set fld = Nothing
   Set tdf = Nothing

   CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh

   Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("UserActivityLog", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

   rs.AddNew
   rs!Owner_ID = 0
   rs!Activity = "Logon"
   rs!CurrentForm = "Logon"
   rs!LastForm = "None"
   rs!Datestamp = #1/1/1900#
   rs!Timestamp = #1/1/1900#
   rs!UserName = "None"
   rs!User_ID = 0
   rs!UserTypeID = 0
   rs.Update
   rs.Requery

   DoCmd.Close acTable, "UserActivityLog", acSaveYes

   Set rs = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing
End Function
```